# Amazon S3 Access Denied only in CopyObject

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm upload files from nodejs script and when I try to copy object I'm getting Access Denied error, if I try to delete the object or to get it  - there is no problem and it success.

Is there anything spacial in the CopyObject?

```
params = {
     "Bucket": "buacket-name",
     "CopySource": "source-path/object.txt",
     "Key": "source-path/object2.txt"
};

s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data)); // With a function for success or error.
```

Answer (score 19):

Solved it! The problem was in my CopySource path, it needs to have the bucket name first, like so: backet-name/objectkey

Comment: Same here, I thought something missing in the policy.

Answer (score 12):

Per the AWS S3 [copyObject docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property), the CopySource parameter should include the bucket and key names. For example:

```
var params = {
  CopySource: 'source_bucket/source_key',
  Bucket: 'destination_bucket_name',
  Key: 'destination_key'
};

s3.copyObject(params, function(error, data) {

  // error check
  if (error) {
    console.log(error, error.stack);
  }

  console.log('S3 object copied');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue to yours in that `copyObject` produced a 403 "Access Denied" response, but a `getObject` followed by a `putObject` worked fine. In my case, I did have the correct syntax for the `CopySource` parameter.

The solution to my problem was to add the `s3:GetObjectTagging` and `s3:PutObjectTagging` permissions to the IAM role performing the copy, since the copyObject operation will attempt to copy the tags over. I know this isn't the solution to your problem, but I'm putting this down answer in case someone else has something very similar.

Unfortunately, the documentation for the [Node.JS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) and the [S3 service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) do not mention this permission requirement. I learned the solution in an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201496/2909636).