# Getting Access Denied when trying to copy file from one path to another within same bucket on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, access-denied

Trying to copy the file to a different location within same bucket

$ **aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/files/qa/test/ac.png s3://bucket1/qa/temp/ac.png**

**copy failed**: s3://bucket1/files/qa/test/ac.png to s3://bucket1/qa/temp/ac.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: **Access Denied**

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have below permission in your Iam policy on that bucket because Copy operation uses below permissions.

s3:GetObject
s3:PutObject
S3:GetObjectTagging
S3:PutObjectTagging

If the object is encrypted using an AWS KMS key, then confirm that your IAM identity has the correct permissions to the key. If your IAM identity and AWS KMS key belong to the same account, then confirm that your key policy grants the required AWS KMS permissions.