# Access Denied when doing copyObject using AWS S3 SDK for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I am tring to copy an existing object inside another object of same bucket,it is throwing an error of Access Denied even though I am able to list all objects and create new objects.

```
 //configuring parameters
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

 AWS.config.update({
   accessKeyId: //iam user's access key,
   secretAccessKey: //iam user's secret key,
 });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var params = {
        Bucket: `mybucket`,
        CopySource: `filepath`,
        Key: `filenewpath`,
      };

  const result = await s3.copyObject(params).promise();
```

Tried changing bucket access to all and setting up the policy for bucket with following policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1682423703415",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1682423694567",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::832462061628:user/developer1"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::salesforcecvfiles"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are your *actual* parameter for `Bucket`, `CopySource` and `Key`? Do you know what the `CopySource` in particular is supposed to be?

Comment: Unless you are very confident in your knowledge of S3 bucket policies, you should almost certainly be using an IAM policy here, not an S3 bucket policy, to grant permissions to an IAM user.

Comment: @luk2302 I have copied this snippet from the AWS docs site itself and it works fine when creating a new object. The bucket is my bucket name, CopySource is the key for an already existing object and the Key is where and with what name I want the copy.

Comment: @jarmod That means I should change iam policy for each I am user?

Comment: CopySource needs to contain both the bucket AND the key, read the docs.

Comment: @luk2302 made the changes like this `{
  Bucket: 'salesforcecvfiles',
  CopySource: 'salesforcecvfiles/developer1/Account/BurlingtonTextilesCorpofAmerica/unnamed.jpg',
  Key: 'salesforcecvfiles/developer1/Account/BurlingtonTextilesCorpofAmerica/myimage.jpg'
}` and now it is giving me a response of `{
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
  CopyObjectResult: {
    ETag: '"66151814a275a158a8363a9c81e7047d"',
    LastModified: 2023-04-26T07:19:57.000Z
  }
}` but still, the copy is not being generated.

Comment: The response says something different. The response says that it worked and the new object has an etag of ...

Comment: @luk2302 yes it says that, but when I am listing all the objects, it is not being displayed or available.

Comment: On the IAM policy vs. S3 bucket policy comment, it is generally better to use the former to grant permissions when possible. You can do this at an individual IAM user level or you can do it for an IAM group (of IAM users).

Comment: @jarmod What are the necessary policies for copy object?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692342/amazon-s3-access-denied-only-in-copyobject